# populate a numpy array with a normal array

Tags: python, list, numpy

```
connum = np.empty((160,160))
confidence = [2142,213124,23123,34324,4545,56634,343,45435,12312,4543,343]
```

I have the list `confidence` and the numpy array `connum` how can i populate the empy numpy array with the elements of the list `confidence`

Comment: you dont want `numpy.array(confidence)` ?

Comment: If you are trying to convert 1-D list to 2-D array, you can do:       `connum = np.array(confidence).reshape(160,160)`

Comment: `confidence` has `11` elements, but `connum` has `160*160 = 25600` elements.  How do you want to distribute your eleven elements into the large array?

Comment: its not the correct size, what would be the point in showing you `25600` elements of my `confidence`?

Comment: Why don't you create a minimal example where you adjust the size of `connum` to that of the `confidence` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If confidence is a list with 25600 elements, just do:

```
connum = np.array(confidence).reshape((160,160))
```